# How to select multiple radio buttons and calculate total price?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jradiobutton, jspinner

I  am implementing a coffee shop menu and have some troubles with radio buttons and spinners.

How can I calculate the total price for multiple radio buttons each with a subtotal price? Because for now, I can calculate the total for just one product.

Should I add a radio button group or something like that?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    double Total = 0.0;
    if(rbCappucino.isSelected()){
        String Cappucino = chboxCappucino.getValue().toString();
         int boom1 = Integer.parseInt(Cappucino);
        Total = boom1 * 1.0;
    }
    else if(rbAmericano.isSelected()){
        String Americano = chboxAmericano.getValue().toString();
         int boom2 = Integer.parseInt(Americano);
        Total = boom2 * 1.50;
    }
    else if(rbLatte.isSelected()){
        String Latte = chboxLatte.getValue().toString();
         int boom3 = Integer.parseInt(Latte);
        Total = boom3 * 2.50;
    }
    
    totalText.setText(Double.toString(Total));
}
```

[image: This is my result]

Comment: *how it will help me with counting the total ?* - you need to create a method like `calculateTotal()`. This method would be invokes any time the user selects a product or quantity. Basically you would move the logic from above to this method. Then you would get rid of the "else" logic and just check the state of each checkbox. If selected then you add the calculated value to the "total". Note, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Actually, while @camickr & CPU made some good suggestions, the logic of this GUI does not require either radio buttons *or* checkboxes. Multiply the number in the spinner with the unit price for each coffee type (`subtotal = thisCoffeePrice x numberCups;`). Add them progressively to the total (`total += subtotal;`) for the total price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javax.swing.JRadioButton` was created to select exactly one option so in your case you should add `javax.swing.JCheckBox` instead

Comment: Let it be . I will use ```JCheckBox``` but how it will help me with counting the total ? I mean how can i implement my calculation part? Thanks for answer