# How to get the result of only CHECKED checkboxes

Tags: java, swing

I am doing pet project and using NetBeans JFrame.
I facing with a problem , i can count only one checked chexBox Total . But how can i implement a method or smth, that can help to count all checked chexBoxes' Total. Would be very glad for answer
How can i implement and count checked prices?
Here is my code and Screenshot below

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

 
// TODO add your handling code here:
                double Total = 0.0;
              
               if(cbCappuccino.isSelected()){
                    String Cappucino = chboxCappucino.getValue().toString();
                     int boom1 = Integer.parseInt(Cappucino);
                    Total =  boom1 * 1.0;
                }
                else if(cbAmericano.isSelected()){
                    String Americano = chboxAmericano.getValue().toString();
                     int boom2 = Integer.parseInt(Americano);
                    Total = Total+boom2 * 1.50;
               }
               else if(cbLatte.isSelected()){
                    String Latte = chboxLatte.getValue().toString();
                     int boom3 = Integer.parseInt(Latte);
                    Total = Total + boom3 * 2.50;
               } 
                
                totalText.setText(Double.toString(Total));

    }
```

and my screenshot
[image: here i unfortunately i can just count only Cappuccino's price]

Comment: Split it up into single `if`-statements instead of `if-else` blocks, so that each checkbox is checked unrelated to the others.

Comment: And change in the first if `Total = boom1 * 1.0;` for `Total = Total + boom1 * 1.0;`. In this case it will not make a difference, but it's more logical. And if later you add a block you won't have to change it.

Comment: oh my god! Thanks!

Comment: The advice given in the previous comments should work. However, consider representing each item as an object (for example  `Item extends JPanel`) encapsulating a checkbox, combobox and label, and some properties such as name, cost, quantity, is-selected and total.

Comment: (1-) Why are you reposting this question? You were given suggestions in your last question on this topic and have made not changes to the posted code. In addition to the suggestions repeated here the above code should be moved to a method which can be invoked when the quantity is changed so the calculations are done dynamically. This provides the most accurate feedback to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better OOP solution consider representing each item as an object encapsulating the view and properties of a single line item:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Item extends JPanel{

    private final JCheckBox selected;
    private final JComboBox<Integer> qty;
    private final double price;
    private final String name;
    private static final Integer[] QTYS = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    public Item(String name, double price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        selected = new JCheckBox(name, false);
        qty = new JComboBox<>(QTYS);
        qty.setSelectedIndex(0);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 15, 0));
        add(selected);
        add(qty);
        JLabel cost = new JLabel(String.format("%,.2f", price), JLabel.CENTER);
        add(cost);
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected.isSelected();
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return (int)qty.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public double getTotal() {
        return isSelected() ? getQty()*getPrice() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Todo:

- Add `clear()` method
- improve the posted code by splitting it into two classes: a model and a view.

Side note: consider using a `JList`as a parent container for all Items.

Answer (score 0):

Like @maloomeister and @vincrichaud adviced i did like this:

```
              
               if(cbCappuccino.isSelected()){
                    String Cappucino = chboxCappucino.getValue().toString();
                     int boom1 = Integer.parseInt(Cappucino);
                    Total = Total+ boom1 * 1.0;
                }
                 if(cbAmericano.isSelected()){
                    String Americano = chboxAmericano.getValue().toString();
                     int boom2 = Integer.parseInt(Americano);
                    Total = Total+boom2 * 1.50;
               }
                if(cbLatte.isSelected()){
                    String Latte = chboxLatte.getValue().toString();
                     int boom3 = Integer.parseInt(Latte);
                    Total = Total + boom3 * 2.50;
               } 
                
                totalText.setText(Double.toString(Total));
```

i just take out if-else statements and just put if statements, and added
`Total = Total + etc`

Comment: *i just take out if-else statements* - and you were given that advice in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69857351/how-to-select-multiple-radio-buttons-and-calculate-total-price. It's frustrating when we take the time to help and you ignore the suggestions given. That wastes our time and the time of the people who repeated the advice here.

Comment: (1-) *and added Total = Total + etc* - then the coded posted as an answer should show that. Why post code that only removes the "else" and not include that. Make the answer complete.